# NameError: name 'minimum' is not defined

Tags: matplotlib

i am creating a histogram with 10 bins and plot it and then Save the resulting plot in hist1.png and i am trying to pass minimum value 0.0 and maximum value 100.0 using the def function below however I am getting an error "NameError: name 'minimum' is not defined" from the code below:

```py
# My dataset
data = np.loadtxt('math_scores.txt')

#Function to calculate the length of bins
def buildHisto (data, numbins, minimum, maximum):
    histo= maximum - minimum
    return histo

histo = buildHisto(data, 10, 0.0, 100.0)
plotHisto(histo, 'histo1.png', minimum, maximum, plotinline = True)
```

Comment: `minimum` and `maximum` are only defined locally inside your `buildHisto` function. When you try to call plotHisto, you try to use them, but they have not been defined globally, so hence the error

Comment: you also try to return `histo` from `buildHisto`, but never calculate it, so it's unclear what you are trying to do there

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is that how i can pass minimum to get value 0.0 and maximum to get this value 100.0

Comment: Maybe you want `plotHisto(data, 'histo1.png', data.min(), data.max(), plotinline=True)`? The function `buildHisto` ignores the `data` and `numbins`, while calling `plotHisto` without the data isn't very useful. You should carefully rethink what it is you want to achieve, and provide more information.